# How to use delays in Arduino code?

Tags: c, multithreading, arduino, delay

Is there a way I can use the [delay command](http://arduino.cc/de/Reference/Delay) and have something else running in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinda, [if you use interrupts](http://blog.makezine.com/2012/01/25/how-to-arduino-interrupts/). `delay` itself uses these. But it's not as elegant as a multi-threaded solution (which is probably what you're looking for). There is a [Multi-Threading](http://www.kwartzlab.ca/2010/09/arduino-multi-threading-librar/) library for Arduino but I'm not sure how well, or even if, it works.

The Arduino is only capable of running a single thread at a time meaning it can only *do* one thing at a time. You can use interrupts to literally interrupt the normal flow of your code but it's still technically not executing at the same time. The library I linked to attempts to implement what you might call a crude "hyper-threaded" solution. Two threads executing in tandem on a single physical processing core.

Comment: Before multicore processors, there were many ''multithreaded'' processors, but none of them technically executed at the same time. Still though, they could do what can be considered true multithreading in a way that Arduino cannot do. The main difference being the way the stack and registers are saved and restored. That said, interrupts are a pretty good way to fake multithreading.

Comment: @Octopus yep. Intel's hyper-threading technology is a great example of that on a mass scale. All those Pentium 4 HTs that shipped before the introduction of the Core 2 Duo.

Answer (score 1):

If you need other code to execute, you need to learn how to program with millis().  This involved converting your code from "step by step" execution to a time-based state machine.

For example if you want a LED to flash, you have two states for that LED:  On and Off.  You change the state when enough time has elapsed.

Here are a series of examples of how to convert delay()-based code into millis()-based code:
http://www.cmiyc.com/blog/2011/01/06/millis-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Usually all you need is a timer and a ISR routine. You won't manage to live without Interrupts :P [Here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Interrupts) you can find a good explanation about this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JamesC4S, state machine is probably the right formalism to use in your case. You could for example try the [ThingML](http://www.ThingML.org) language (which uses components, state machines, etc), and which compiles to Arduino code. A simple example [can be found here](https://github.com/ffleurey/ThingML/blob/master/org.thingml.samples/src/main/thingml/samples/blink2leds.thingml).